# Infragistics TabControl inherit template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, infragistics

I am using infragistics wpf tabcontrol controls. Look at the following code snippet.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicTabControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:igWindows="http://infragistics.com/Windows"
        xmlns:igDP="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <igWindows:XamTabControl Name="xamTabCtrl" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" Theme="Metro">
            <igWindows:XamTabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Label Content="{Binding Header}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </igWindows:XamTabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <igWindows:XamTabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <igDP:XamDataGrid Theme="Metro"
                  DataSource="{Binding Logins}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </igWindows:XamTabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </igWindows:XamTabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The datagrid looks like
[image: Datagrid]

As you can see the xaml above, I overwrite the ItemTemplate property wit label, that cause different appearance from infragistics default style and the default looks like

[image: Default]

How can I inherit ItemTemplate style from infragistics?

**Update**

I try following:

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicTabControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:igWindows="http://infragistics.com/Windows"
        xmlns:igDP="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="700">
    <Grid>
        <igWindows:XamTabControl Name="xamTabCtrl" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" Theme="Metro">
            <igWindows:XamTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type igWindows:TabItemEx}" BasedOn="">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Header}" />
                </Style>
            </igWindows:XamTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <igWindows:XamTabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <igDP:XamDataGrid Theme="Metro"
                  DataSource="{Binding Logins}" IsGroupByAreaExpanded="False" GroupByAreaLocation="None" GroupByAreaMode="DefaultFieldLayoutOnly"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </igWindows:XamTabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </igWindows:XamTabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Everything works fine, except the theme does not take it with. What do I have to write in baseOn property?